# How to disable the multiple selection of qgraphicsitem?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I am new to Qt. It seems the default for multiple selection of qgraphicsitem is to press ctrl button.
But is it possible to disable this function? Or reload this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is controlled by the items' flags. To disable selection for a particular item, do

```
item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, false);
```

If you want to completly disable selecting items for a `QGraphicsScene` regardless of the item flags I would recommend to connect `QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged` to `QGraphicsScene::clearSelection`.

If you want to disable multiple selection I suggest the following:

- Subclass QGraphicsScene and keep a pointer `lastSelection` to a QGraphicsItem around
- Create a slot connected to `QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged`
- Check `selectedItems`:

  - it's empty: nothing to do (=nothing selected)
  - contains only `lastSelection`: nothing to do (=selection didn't really change)
  - contains one item, not `lastSelection`: set `lastSelection` to that item (=one item selected for the first time)
  - contains two items: One must be `lastSelection`. Remove that one from the selection (`lastSelection->setSelected(false);`), set `lastSelection` to the remaining item. (=another item was selected, move selection to it)

You might need to block signals during modifying the selection inside the slot.

Comment: Hi, but I still want to keep normal selection ability, I only want to disable the multiple selection...

Comment: Sorry, but what's the purpose of blocking signals during modifying the selection inside a slot?

Comment: I'm not sure who handles the selection behind the scenes. If the items do it, it might be possible to create a signal loop when modifying the selection from a selectionChanged slot. Thus it might be necessary to block signals.

Comment: @dom0 +1 but there is no need to block signals if you do the checks in the order that you described

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to disable multiple selection is:

1. Create your own Dirived class from `QGraphicsItem`.
2. Overload the protected `mousePressEvent` function and disable `ControlModifier`:

   ```
   protected:
       void YourOwnQGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
       {
           if(mouseEvent->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
           {
               mouseEvent->ignore();
           }
           else
           {
               QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
               //Do what you want...
           }
       }
   ```